# How to change color of ActionBar's Title Text on Android 4.3 api 18

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I am using appcompat v7 library to support action bars in api level 8 and up. I am trying to change the color of title text of action bar.

Color of title text is changing in GingerBread but when I run the app on my phone with JellyBean the color doesn't change.

**On GingerBread Title Color changes to Red:**

[image]

**On JellyBean it remains black:**

[image]

Here are my styles.xml:

**styles.xml:**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleBarTextColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleBarTextColor" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**styles.xml for v-11:**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**styles.xml for v-14:**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Mainfest:**

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found Solution to my own problem :

I have to use `android:actionBarStyle` , `android:titleTextStyle` and `android:textColor` for api level 14 and up.

So the styles.xml for v-11 will be:

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleBarTextColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleBarTextColor" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: I don't know why but for me it's work only if I remove "android:" <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>   <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleBarTextColor</item>

Answer (score 0):

I'll use the following within my styles for the current theme in order to update the text color in the ActionBar:

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/Red</item>
```

which seems to work for me across the latest OS releases.

Comment: I only want to change the color of title thats why I have used TitleBarTextColor. I think your solution will effect the text on entire ActionBar like subtext, menu text etc.

Comment: You are right that is true.  It modifies the entire ActionBar.  Not sure if I have managed what you are asking in any of the applications I have worked upon (or had the need yet).